# Pass value to the same level component

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I want to pass value of things Array to the component on the same level.
Structure of my app is:

- sidebar.component
- data.service
- body.component.

In sidebar component I got button and on click  I'm hitting to an API.

sidebar.component.ts

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  things : Thing [] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onClick(user): void {
    this.dataService.getThings(user.item.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.things = data.items;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

data.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getThings(id): Observable<ThingsResources> {
    return this.httpClient.get<ThingsResources>(this.thingsUrl + id);
  }
}
```

sidebar.html

```html
<div>
    <ng-container *ngFor= "let things of things">
        <div>
            <span>{{things.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

And displaying the thing values works good in sidebar.html but I want to have this values in body to display it in

body.html

```html
<div>
    <ng-container *ngFor= "let things of things">
        <div>
            <span>{{things.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Sidebar and body components aren't child and parent component. I guess that @Input and @Output will not work.
Is there any idea how to pass this values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- i see conflict here, u declared var with same name of your container.

```
<ng-container *ngFor= "let things of things">
```

2- why `ng-container` !! u can loop in the div

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor= "let thing of things">
        <span>{{ thing.name }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

3- You can pass value by make a `GetThings` function in your `DataService` and just call that function like that (after inject it in `Body`)

```
<div *ngFor= "let thing of dataServ.GetThings()">
```

OR you can make a static variable in `sidebar`.

Comment: I fixed these two things like you mentioned above. 
Body is my component. And sidebar is my component too. 
In this case I want to pass things from sidebar to body to use it in my body.html

Comment: as i see u already have Service, why not just inject this service in `Body` and get data from it. (that after u already set your data in the Service form `sidebar`) OR u can use static variable in `Sidebar`.

Comment: i did like you said via service. I moved my method to service, created getter and use it in body component. Thanks